# GET data from index resource via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am probably making this more difficult than it needs to be, but I am simply trying to grab all the data from an index resource and have them load VIA a button and an ajax request. I am using a serializer to clean up the JSON.

Both "/categories" (index) and "/total_user_donations" are in the `CategoriesController`. Currently, the "/total_user_donations" template shows the current user's individual donations. What I want to do is add a button that shows ALL individual donations, via the index resource (`Category.all` data is what I want) through an AJAX request.

Pertinent code is below:

Here is index route I am looking to pull from:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_not_logged_in

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end 

  def total_user_donation
    @total_user_donation = Category.total_user_donation(current_user)
  end
end
```

Here is where I want my response data to go. See table below:

```
<button class="js-more">To see EVERY donation on the website, click here</button><br><br>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Donation Count</th>
    <th>Toilet Paper</th>
    <th>Diapers</th>
    <th>Dental Hygiene</th>
    <th>First Aid</th>
    <th>General Hygiene</th>
    <th>Underwear and Socks</th>
    <th>Blankets</th>
    <th>School Supplies</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="id"></td>
    <td id="toiletPaper"></td>
    <td id="diapers"></td>
    <td id="dentalHygiene"></td>
    <td id="firstAid"></td>
    <td id="generalHygiene"></td>
    <td id="underwearSocks"></td>
    <td id="blankets"></td>
    <td id="schoolSupplies"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table above is located at route "/total_user_donations".

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".js-more").click(function() {
    $.get("/categories.json"), function(category) {
      $("#id").text(category["id"]);
      $("#toiletPaper").text(category["toilet_paper"]);
      $("#diapers").text(category["diapers"]);
      $("#firstAid").text(category["first_aid"]);
      $("#generalHygiene").text(category["general_hygiene"]);
      $("#underwearSocks").text(category["underwear_socks"]);
      $("#dentalHygiene").text(category["dental_hygiene"]);
      $("#blankets").text(category["blankets"]);
      $("#schoolSupplies").text(category["school_supplies"]);
    }
  });
});
```

**Update:** I am trying to do this without `remote: true`.

Comment below made me realize my questions weren't that obvious, so here they are.

1. Why isn't the data showing up on the table? What am I missing?
2. Why won't clicking the `.js-more` button show any type of request being made in console? Only way the request works is if I manually copy/paste the function into the console. And, even then, it returns a length = 1 document.. not the data I need.

Comment: Two part I suppose:

1.  Why isn't the data showing up on the table?  What am I missing?

2.  Why won't clicking the button show any type of request being made in console?  Only way any activity shows up is if I directly copy/paste the JS code in the browser.

Comment: Can you post server logs for your AJAX?

Comment: Another thing, check your browser console for any JavaScript errors.

Comment: That is the part that is frustrating because I believe I have set up my app to handle JS fine.  When I click the button, there isn't any form of activity in the console.

Now, if I copy paste the JS function above and click the button, it loads it just fine.  As in, it completes a GET request successfully.. it still doesn't load the data I need.

Comment: Is the JavaScript you wrote present on your HTML page when it loads? Make sure it is there by checking scripts in browser.

Comment: Oh i see... duh.  I am brand new to JS.  Well, I see only one categories.self.

I manually made a categories.js becacuse I am not use coffeescript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the ")" after "/categories.json" and put it behind the success-function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".js-more").click(function() {
    $.get("/categories.json", function(category) {
      $("#id").text(category["id"]);
      $("#toiletPaper").text(category["toilet_paper"]);
      $("#diapers").text(category["diapers"]);
      $("#firstAid").text(category["first_aid"]);
      $("#generalHygiene").text(category["general_hygiene"]);
      $("#underwearSocks").text(category["underwear_socks"]);
      $("#dentalHygiene").text(category["dental_hygiene"]);
      $("#blankets").text(category["blankets"]);
      $("#schoolSupplies").text(category["school_supplies"]);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this working? do you have a demo snippet to run?

Best,
Will